# Poll a particular directory in S3 for new files using Java

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have to write a Java code which will poll S3 directory at regular interval of time to get the path of new files? I don't want to use Lambda function to trigger event. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why did you tag the question with `aws-lambda` if you don't want to use Lambda? Why don't you want to use S3's event functionality to push new object events to your Java application?

Comment: What @MarkB said... Why tag and why don’t you want to use the S3 events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regularly scanning an Amazon S3 bucket is not efficient — buckets can be quite large, requiring many API calls, and work is performed even if no new files have been added.

The better way to implement this is:

- Configure an **Amazon S3 Event** that will trigger an AWS Lambda function when a new file is created
- The **AWS Lambda function** will receive the Bucket and Key of the new object via the `event` field, so that it can perform actions on the new object

This is a simple, clean solution compared to running code at regular intervals to scan for new objects.